# What Can I Do If My App/Game Is Rejected Due to the Update Pop-up Failing to Display on a Mobile Phone with HMS Core (APK) 2.5.3 or Earlier?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect, huawei-iap

My project has integrated HUAWEI IAP and other services using the HMS Core SDK 4.x. However, the app is rejected during Huawei app review, for an update pop-up cannot be displayed on a mobile phone with HMS Core (APK) 2.5.3 or earlier.
I have tried to reoccur this problem by uninstall and update HMS Core to version of 2.5.3 .But the operation fail. how can i reoccur the problem and solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because the HMS Core (APK) version on your phone is earlier than 2.5.3. Each of the following solutions can be used to reoccur the problem.

- Find a Huawei phone and perform the following steps.Go to **Settings > Apps > Apps**, then searched for and tapped HMS Core (APK). On the displayed page, tapped the button in the upper right corner, and chose to uninstall the APK update.
- If the uninstallation fails, find a non-Huawei phone and uninstall
  HMS Core (APK).
- If the Huawei phone has been rooted, just uninstall HMS Core (APK).

You can try to Log analysis and check the project code,The problem may be due to the input parameter in your project is of the **Context** type, rather than the **Activity** type.

[image]

For Details,check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/iap-0000001050137603-V5?ha_source=hms1).

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe how the operation failed (error, screenshots)?

If you don't turn off **AppGallery** **Auto-update apps**, it will automatically update your HMS Core immediately to the latest version right after you remove HMS Core updates. If this is the case, you will not be able to test your app using HMS Core 2.5.3.

Please make sure that you turn off Auto-update apps in **AppGallery** > **Settings.**

Regardless, you will need to upgrade your IAP to the latest version in order to be approved by AppGallery app review.

[image]

[image]

[image]